# Running Flutter for Web without a web server

Tags: flutter, flutter-web

I'd like to preface this by saying that I'm completely new to both web development and StackOverflow, so please have mercy with me if I could have googled some part of this answer - I did, but didn't find anything. Maybe I just don't know what to search for.

I'm tasked with displaying some external dynamic data on Samsung digital signage display, like a twitter feed and news ticker.
Since the display can display web pages and I worked with Flutter before and absolutely love it, I figured I might as well use Flutter for Web.
I tested whether Flutter works on the display and while an external site made with Flutter (https://flutter.github.io/samples/#/) works perfectly, I won't be able to host my entire website externally, since all business logic and images and other custom-made resources must remain local. (I also can't host it on some internal company server. No servers allowed.)
Luckily, there's a second way of displaying a web page: You can directly upload a zip file with the html and optionally other resources. However, the display doesn't use a local web server for this, so it's essentially the same as double-clicking on the html on your computer and opening it in Chrome.

When I build the web app, zip the entire contents of the ./build/web/ directory and upload it to the display, I get a completely white screen. The same happens when I open index.html with Chrome. Chrome says it can't load local files due to the CORS policy, and I suspect the same is true for the display.
However, when I use a traditional web framework like Bootstrap it loads everything just fine. Maybe this is because it pulls stuff from CDNs, maybe it is because everything is in the same html (the css isn't, though), I don't know.

So the question is: Is there some way or workaround to have Flutter run directly in the browser without the need of an external or local server?

Comment: Try placing your `build/web` folder into the svn/git repo of your project and access it over the browser. This might work because your svn/git repo is hosted internally within your network.

Comment: @AbhilashChandran I don't think that helps. Were you able to solve it?

Comment: @NisanBahar sadly no, I had to abandon Flutter for this project

Answer (score 1):

If you'll be running the web app from `/build/web` directly, you'll be getting CORS policy errors since it'll be accessing files outside the trusted source. Running the files through a web server will indicate that these assets are trusted. If you really need to run the index.html file from `/build/web` directly, you'll need to [disable web security](https://medium.com/@dmadan86/run-chrome-browser-without-cors-by-disabling-web-security-d124ad4dd2cf) of the web browser.